# Get correct date string from Android PagerDatePicker Library

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using [PagerDatePicker](https://github.com/rspective/PagerDatePicker) library in Android to pick a date and do some work on corresponding date's fragment. But the problem I'm getting is that when I click on a date, I get correct date on corresponding date's textview but not on Toast or Logcat.
When I swipe on the screen (since, it is a viewpager, I can just swipe to move to the next date as shown [here](https://github.com/rspective/PagerDatePicker/blob/master/art/app_1.1.0.gif)),or click on any date, I get correct date on the textView but on Logcat or Toast, it shows the date of a day after or a day before the selected date.
How is it possible that it is showing correct text on textView and incorrect string on Toast/Logcat.

There are 3 Java files - MainActivity.java -

```
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fl_main_container, DatePickerDefaultFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
    }

}
```

DatePickerDefaultFragment.java -

```
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;  
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;  
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;  
import android.util.Log;  
import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.ViewGroup;  
import android.widget.Toast;  

import org.joda.time.DateTime;  
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;  
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;  
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  

import java.text.ParseException;  
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  

import pl.rspective.pagerdatepicker.PagerDatePickerDateFormat;  
import pl.rspective.pagerdatepicker.adapter.DatePagerFragmentAdapter;  
import pl.rspective.pagerdatepicker.adapter.DefaultDateAdapter;  
import pl.rspective.pagerdatepicker.model.DateItem;  
import pl.rspective.pagerdatepicker.view.DateRecyclerView;  
import pl.rspective.pagerdatepicker.view.RecyclerViewInsetDecoration;  

public class DatePickerDefaultFragment extends Fragment {

    private DateRecyclerView dateList;
    private ViewPager pager;
    LocalDate localDate;
    DateTime dateTime;

    public static DatePickerDefaultFragment newInstance() {
        return new DatePickerDefaultFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_picker_default, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        dateList = (DateRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_list);

        // [Setting today's date in the DatePicker.]
        localDate = new LocalDate();
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), localDate.toString(fmt));
        String DATE_START = localDate.toString(fmt);
        String DATE_END = localDate.plusYears(5).toString(fmt);
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), DATE_END);
        // [END]

        dateList.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewInsetDecoration(getActivity(), R.dimen.date_card_insets));

        Date start = null;
        Date end = null;
        Date defaultDate = null;

        try {
            start = PagerDatePickerDateFormat.DATE_PICKER_DD_MM_YYYY_FORMAT.parse(DATE_START);
            end = PagerDatePickerDateFormat.DATE_PICKER_DD_MM_YYYY_FORMAT.parse(DATE_END);

            defaultDate = PagerDatePickerDateFormat.DATE_PICKER_DD_MM_YYYY_FORMAT.parse(DATE_START );

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dateList.setAdapter(new DefaultDateAdapter(start, end, defaultDate));

        DatePagerFragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter = new DatePagerFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager(), dateList.getDateAdapter()) {
            @Override
            protected Fragment getFragment(int position, long date) {
                return SimplePageFragment.newInstance(position, date);
            }
        };

        pager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
        dateList.setPager(pager);

        dateList.setDatePickerListener(new DateRecyclerView.DatePickerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDatePickerItemClick(DateItem dateItem, int position) {
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Date - " + simpleDateFormat.format(dateItem.getDate()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDatePickerPageSelected(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDatePickerPageStateChanged(int state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDatePickerPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and SimplePageFragment.java -

```
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;  
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;  
import android.util.Log;  
import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.ViewGroup;  
import android.widget.TextView;  

import org.joda.time.DateTime;  
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;  
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  

public class SimplePageFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    private static final String DATE_PICKER_DATE_KEY = "date_picker_date_key";
    private static final String DATE_PICKER_POSITION_KEY = "date_picker_position_key";
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private TextView tvDate;
    private TextView tvPosition;

    private int position;
    private long date;
    private DateTime dateTime;

    public static SimplePageFragment newInstance(int position, long date) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(DATE_PICKER_POSITION_KEY, position);
        bundle.putLong(DATE_PICKER_DATE_KEY, date);

        SimplePageFragment simplePageFragment = new SimplePageFragment();
        simplePageFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return simplePageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        position = getArguments().getInt(DATE_PICKER_POSITION_KEY, -1);
        date = getArguments().getLong(DATE_PICKER_DATE_KEY, -1);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_simple, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_date_label);
        tvPosition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_position_label);

        dateTime = new DateTime(date);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Log.i(TAG, dateTime.toString(formatter));
//        tvDate.setText("fun");
        String ss = dateTime.toString(formatter);
        tvDate.setText(ss);
//        Log.e("DATE", "" + dateTime.toString(formatter));

        Log.e("DATE2", ss);
//        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        tvPosition.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    }

}
```

and there's this fragment_page_simple.xml layout used in SimplePageFragment -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff343434"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#0f0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_position_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#ffff3f49"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please enhance your question by providing your source code.

Comment: @Mischback okay...I'm editing it..

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick shoot but did you try to use standard java Date classes. The library is based on them, you are using JodaTime library. This shouldn't do any difference but who knows. It's really weird that you have correct value in textView and wrong in logcat.

I checked the demo app, and I am getting correct values in logcat/toast - I used standard Java date class.

Answer (score 0):

final SimpleDateFormat SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

```
    dateList = (DateRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_list);
    dateList.setDatePickerListener(new DateRecyclerView.DatePickerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDatePickerItemClick(DateItem dateItem, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "date = " + SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(dateItem.getDate()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            someTextView.setText(SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(dateItem.getDate()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDatePickerPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDatePickerPageStateChanged(int state) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDatePickerPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }
    });
```